# .tmux.conf: update status commands on panel focus

Tags: git, bash, shell, tmux

I have a line in my .tmux.conf which simply shows me the git branch I am on.

`set                 -g status-right ' #[bg=colour33] Branch #[(git branch)] '`

When working in tmux, I regularly have panels in different directories. So my question becomes, is there a way to have the status command re-execute based on my "panel's cwd", instead of what it is doing now, where it seems to just hold onto the directory I was in when tmux was first opened.. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In newer versions of tmux, you can use `pane_current_path` to achieve this:

```
set -g status-right '#(cd #{pane_current_path}; git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)'
```

Answer (score 1):

See this answer - [Pane Title in Tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747952/pane-title-in-tmux) - you would probably need to override the `chpwd` function which is invoked whenever you change working directories in bash/zsh.