# tmuxinator only runs commands of first pane correctly

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I have a `.tmuxinator.yml` which looks like this:

```yaml
pre_window:
windows:
  - workspace:
      layout: even-vertical
      panes:
        - health:
            - printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' 'healthcheck'
            - cd dev-env
            - clear
        - work:
            - printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' 'workspace'
            - clear
  - api:
      layout: even-vertical
      panes:
        - database:
            - printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' 'api-database'
            - cd api
            - docker-compose up
        - server:
            - printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' 'api'
            - cd api
            - yarn watch
        - workspace:
            - printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' 'api-workspace'
            - cd api
            - clear
```

This used to work but now it only runs the first pane commands correctly which means it just doesn't call the commands after the `printf ...` statements for any other than the first one in each window.

Update: removing the `printf ...' statements seems to fix it but I would like to keep them.

I'm using

- tmux 3.2a
- tmuxinator 3.0.1
- macOS 12.0.1 (Monterey - the problem is not caused by Monterey as the problem did exist before)

I've double checked the line endings using `cat -e .tmuxinator.yml`.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce on Debian 11.1, tmux 3.1c and tmuxinator 3.0.1. What system are you on? Is it possible there's an issue with line endings or whitespace in your actual config? You may want to try running your config through [a YAML validator](https://yamlvalidator.com/).

Comment: I've updated the question with details about my system.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler what's the `printf` is doing ?

Comment: @Chandan https://stackoverflow.com/a/41819567/90800