# Pane Title in Tmux .conf File

Tags: tmux, pane

I'm setting up a window template script in the tmux.conf file and want to have a statement that add a pane title.
In a related post 2019 the solution is partially provided by adding a pane title from the command line - [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747952/pane-title-in-tmux) A solution is quoted below:-

```
 tmux select-pane -t {pane} -T {title}

    Examples:
    tmux select-pane -T title1          # Change title of current pane
    tmux select-pane -t 1 -T title2     # Change title of pane 1 in current window
    tmux select-pane -t 2.1 -T title3   # Change title of pane 1 in window 2`
```

How do I translate this into a line in the .tmux.conf file?

I've tried the following;

send-keys 'tmux select-pane -t 1 -T titles' C-m ; 
select-pane -t 1 -T titles C-m ; 
select-pane -t 1-T titles

Comment: you've tried so what's the result? what problems do you hit?

Comment: I'm now very confused. sounds like you are talking about another problem?

Comment: please clarify and update your question.

Comment: I'm running Tmux on a DO droplet.
  This question started out as a problem with the pane title arguments not seeming to work when inserted into the .tmux.conf file.
  Various argument arrangements, as above, were tried with no effect; sorcing of the conf file was done between changes. 
  I then suspecting that no changes made to the conf file were been reflected in the window. This was confirmed by making wholesale changes to the conf without result.

Comment: The server was killed and restarted. Changes to the conf file still had no effect on the window layout. However on restarting the session was restored automatically - i use plugins; tmux-continuum & tmux-resurrect.
  I deleted these two plugins and restarted the session. Changes to the conf file were now being reflected in the window layout.
  Deleting these two plugins seems to be a bit of a work-around but it provided a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Finally - although changes to the config file seem to be effected by the continuum & reurrect plugins I found that in order for this to work:-

```
    select-pane -T title1          # Change title of current pane
    select-pane -t 1 -T title2     # Change title of pane 1 in current window
    select-pane -t 2.1 -T title3   # Change title of pane 1 in window 2
```

You had to first add the following to the conf file:-

```
    set -g pane-border-format "#{pane_index} #{pane_current_command}"
```